# face issues in loop and break in php

Tags: php

I've faced problem that I cant resolve in my simple code

```
foreach(file('num.txt') as $num) {
    foreach(file('char.txt') as $char) {

        echo $char.$num. "<br>";
        if($char=="C"&&$num==3){
            echo 'Found it<br>';
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '----------------------------<br>';

}
```

num.txt contains numbers like this
1
2
3
4
5 per line
char contains character Like A  B  C D per line
. 
and as result
it dose not remove the C3 in text step after break

but i want it like this way without the founded C3

```
A1
B1
C1
D1
--------------
A2
B2
C2
D2
--------------
A3
B3
C3
Found it
D3
--------------
A4
B4
D4
--------------
A5
B5
D5
--------------
```

so C is no longer in the loop and continue if add B5 and so on
Please help i need this assignment

Comment: Elaborate your problem and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: the problem that i got C3 in loop in next step after break i dont know how to fix it
i need to contiune print  without C3 as next step

Comment: Share the output you wanna receive and the num.txt and char.txt

Comment: Also post you txt files content

Comment: Instead of break use continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had regular array, you could remove "C" from it, but since you are getting data implicitly from file, this is the solution. Not the most elegant, but works:

```
// add flag for found value
$found = false;

foreach(file('num.txt') as $num) {
    foreach(file('char.txt') as $char) {

        // condition to show an entry
        if(!$found || $char != "C") {
            echo $char.$num. "<br>";
            if($char == "C" && $num == 3) {
                echo 'Found it<br>';
                // you do not need 'break', remove it and set flag instead
                $found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    echo '----------------------------<br>';

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for ur fast response ^_^but still print C4 -C5 and dose not remove it

Comment: this is not possible :-) so something wrong with getting data from files; replace `file('num.txt')` with `$nums` and assign `$nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];` do the same with chars and assign `$chars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];` if this works, make sure your files return same values (right case, no spaces, etc)

Comment: you were right :*
http://prntscr.com/qjwg4q
but why i cant get it right from txt file

Comment: debug it! get data from files compare with explicit values and if not equal - report and see difference

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will be like this:

```
foreach(file('num.txt') as $num) {
        foreach(file('char.txt') as $char) {
             if($char=="C"&&$num==3){
                echo 'Found it<br>';
                break;
            }
            else{
            echo $char.$num. "<br>";
           }

        }
        echo '----------------------------<br>';

    }
```

Comment: thank you but am afraid not this solution
http://prntscr.com/qjwkuh

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```
<?php
    $arr1 = ['A','B','C','D'];
    $arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
      for($j = 0; $j < count($arr2); $j++){
        if($arr1[$i] == "C" && $arr2[$j] == 3){
          echo "Found It<br/>";
          break;
        }
        echo $arr1[$i]."".$arr2[$j]."<br/>";
      }
      echo "----------------------<br/>";
    }
?>
```

[image]